# Write a function that counts the number of elements in a rosetree

Tags: haskell

Write a function
that counts the number of elements in a rosetree.

I tried counts the number of elements in a rosetree.

```
data RoseTree a = RoseNode a [RoseTree a]
    deriving Show
things :: RoseTree String
things = 
    RoseNode "thing" [
        RoseNode "animal" [
            RoseNode "cat" [], RoseNode "dog" []
        ],

        RoseNode "metal" [
            RoseNode "alloy" [
                RoseNode "steel" [], RoseNode "bronze" []
            ],
            RoseNode "element" [
                RoseNode "gold" [], RoseNode "tin" [], RoseNode "iron" []
            ]
        ],

        RoseNode "fruit" [
            RoseNode "apple" [
                RoseNode "Granny Smith" [], RoseNode "Pink Lady" []
            ],
            RoseNode "banana" [],
            RoseNode "orange" []
        ],

        RoseNode "astronomical object" [
            RoseNode "Planet" [
                RoseNode "Earth" [], RoseNode "Mars" []
            ],
            RoseNode "Star" [
                RoseNode "The Sun" [], RoseNode "Sirius" []
            ],
            RoseNode "Galaxy" [
                RoseNode "Milky Way" []
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

It should be 27, however, it returns 4.

**EDIT:** Here is my attempt:

```
roseSize x = case x of
    RoseNode a [] -> 0
    RoseNode a (x:xs) -> 1 + roseSize (RoseNode a xs)
```

Comment: I tried counts the number of elements in a rosetree.

roseSize x = case x of
        RoseNode a [] -> 0
        RoseNode a (x:xs)->1 + roseSize (RoseNode a xs)

Comment: Where is your function? This is only a data type and a tree. Also, have you looked at Haskell's [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) from the package [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers)? It is a rose tree.

Comment: @SimonShine An attempt was presented in the comments - I just edited it into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It should be 27, however, it returns 4.
>
> ```
> roseSize x = case x of
>   RoseNode a [] -> 0
>   RoseNode a (x:xs) -> 1 + roseSize (RoseNode a xs)
> ```

So you're not counting the sub-trees recursively. Try instead (*fixed: base case to `1`*),

```
roseSize (RoseNode _ []) = 1
roseSize (RoseNode a (t:ts)) = roseSize t + roseSize (RoseNode a ts)
```

The missing part is `roseSize t`.

Otherwise you're only making recursive calls for the first layer of the tree.

If you evaluate your function by hand this becomes apparent,

```
roseSize things
  ~> roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ animals, metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ]
  ~> 1 + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> 1 + 1 + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> 1 + 1 + 1 + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ astronomical_objects ])
  ~> 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [])
  ~> 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

whereas with `roseSize t` in the function body the evaluation becomes

```
roseSize things
  ~> roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ animals, metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ]
  ~> roseSize animals
      + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> roseSize (RoseNode "animal" [ cat, dog ])
      + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> roseSize cat
      + roseSize (RoseNode "animal" [ dog ])
      + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> 1 -- given the base case of 1 instead of 0
      + roseSize (RoseNode "animal" [ dog ])
      + roseSize (RoseNode "thing" [ metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ])
  ~> ...
```

---

As an exercise, making this function explicitly recursive is fine.

But you may want to consider a more general approach, either using higher-order functions [like PF. Castro does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060212/235908), or an existing data structure like [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Tree.html) of [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers):

```
import qualified Data.Tree as T
import           Data.Tree (Tree(..))

things :: Tree String
things = Node "thing" [ animals, metals, fruits, astronomical_objects ]
  where
    animals = Node "animal" (map pure [ "cat", "dog" ])
    metals = Node "metal" [ alloys, elements ]
    alloys = Node "alloy" (map pure [ "steel", "bronze" ])
    elements = Node "element" (map pure [ "gold", "tin", "iron" ])
    fruits = ...
    astronomical_objects = ...
```

Since a `Data.Tree` is `Foldable`, you can use `length` on it.

So it's not necessary to define a custom `roseSize` function.

---

At this point you're counting the *nodes* in a tree, and not the *leaves* of a tree, with *leaves* being the actual objects rather than the *categories* to which they belong. So you may actually be interested in counting the *leaves*.

You could do that by creating a function that finds the leaves:

```
leaves :: Tree a -> [a]
leaves (Node x []) = ... -- x is a leaf
leaves (Node _x ts) = ... -- _x isn't a leaf
```

With this template you can't easily use explicit recursion, i.e. matching on `Node x (t:ts)` and calling `leaves` on `ts`, since then the non-leaf case eventually ends in the base case, making the exhausted category appear as a leaf. But you can use higher-order functions to abstract out the recursion, e.g. `concat`, `map`, or `concatMap` of [`Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:13).

---

Using a library rose tree gives you other advantages, too, for example a bunch of other type class instances (`Applicative` giving you `pure "foo"` to construct a singleton tree / leaf) and a pretty-printing function:

```
> putStrLn $ T.drawTree things
thing
|
+- animal
|  |
|  +- cat
|  |
|  `- dog
|
`- metal
   |
   +- alloy
   |  |
   |  +- steel
   |  |
   |  `- bronze
   |
   ...
```

Comment: Testing in GHCi, this returns 26, not 27. Not sure why though.

Comment: Ah, I don't know either.

Comment: I don't like this recursion, since `roseSize (RoseNode a [t1,t2,t3])` evaluates to `1 + roseSize t1 + 1 + roseSize t2 + 1 + roseSize t3` which looks wrong. Maybe it's correct after all, but I can't convince myself. Those extra `1`s look redundant.

Comment: I think actually it's because it should be `roseSize (RoseNode _ []) = 1`. I think this would also remove the `1+` from the second case, solving @chi's query as well.

Comment: I assume the intent is to count the number of nodes, so if nothing else the base case is wrong: `RoseNode _ []` should result in 1, not 0.

Comment: Also, if the base case is `1`, then the `1 +` should be removed as well from the second case. I mentioned this already but I feel it's important enough to say again.

Comment: Thanks, RobinZigmond and bradrn. :-)

Comment: The base case *must* be 1: this definition does not allow for an empty tree, so `roseSize` should never return 0. A node, however, *could* have no children, meaning the *sum* could evaluate to 0.

Comment: Your answer has illustrated my question clearly and I learn a lot from it. Thank you!!!

Comment: I have done the roseFlatten,                                                   
roseFlatten :: RoseTree a -> [a]
roseFlatten tree = case tree of
  RoseNode x []-> [x]
  RoseNode a (x:xs) -> (roseFlatten x) ++ (roseFlatten (RoseNode a xs))

Comment: @KafaiLaw: `Data.Tree` already has [`flatten`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:flatten). When you flatten a tree, you don't differentiate between leaf nodes and other nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use map and fold with RoseTrees, e.g.:

```
size (RoseNode x xs) = 1 + (sum (map size xs))
```

where sum is just:

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```