# Compute size of rose tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, count, tree, nodes

For an exercise for uni I have to work with rose trees in Haskell, defined as such:

```
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
```

One of the exercises is writing a function `size :: Rose a -> Int` returning the number of nodes for a given tree. The solution I found for this exercise (also on StackOverflow "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060053/write-a-function-that-counts-the-number-of-elements-in-a-rosetree") is the following:

```
size (MkRose _ []) = 1
size (MkRose a (t:ts)) = roseSize t + roseSize (MkRose a ts)
```

But I dont really understand why this is correct. Say you have the following rose tree:
[image]

Does it not miscount the number of nodes. You start from node 1, where `t = MkRose 2 [MkRose 1 (t:ts)]` and `ts = MkRose 3 []`. Now the size of `MkRose 1 ts` is two. and the size of `t` is two aswell. Giving the final answer 4, when clearly there are 3 nodes. Does anyone know where I am mistaken? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not following that picture. Why is there an up arrow?

Comment: @Carl node 1 is a 'child' of node 2

Comment: Trees don’t have cycles

Comment: The value you describe, if I understand correctly, is actually an infinite rose tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not give an incorrect answer for the tree you described<sup>*</sup> -- indeed, it does not give an answer at all. Let us define

```
t = Rose 2 [Rose 1 [t, Rose 3 []]]
```

and then compute:

```
size t
= { unroll defn. of t }
size (Rose 2 [Rose 1 [t, Rose 3 []]])
= { defn. of size, case 2 }
size (Rose 1 [t, Rose 3 []]) + size (Rose 2 [])
= { defn. of size, case 2 }
size t + size (Rose 1 [Rose 3 []]) + size (Rose 2 [])
```

But this first addend, `size t`, is exactly the thing we started out to compute! So we have entered a loop, and will endlessly expand to larger and larger sums.

<sup>*</sup> The tree you described and the graph you drew do *not* represent the same thing. While `t` as defined above will be stored in memory like the graph you drew when using GHC (and probably most sane implementations), its *meaning* is an infinite tree that looks something like this:

```
2 --> 1 --> 2 --> 1 --> 2 --> 1 --> 2 --> 1 --> 2 --> ...
      |           |           |           |
      v           v           v           v
      3           3           3           3
```